# Responsive scaling image

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I know there are a few posts on this and know how to scale images responsively ( if that's a word ) by using `max-width: 100%;` etc etc

What I'm wanting to know and can't figure out is how this site is scaling the images of the dogs in the background? When you re-size the browser window the width and height dimensions are recalculated so that left me thinking a jQuery plugin could be doing this.

Here is the site: http://momentum-demo.squarespace.com/

I've inspected the elements and checked out the styling... nothing too obvious is giving it away but if anyone can shed some light on this it would be great! I'm sure other people could value from this too.

Comment: Yes, you can do that with few lines of javascript..

Comment: They are probably doing something with JavaScript to make it animate like that. I didn't look at how they're doing it, though. IMO, it's annoying. [`background-size:cover;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) in CSS does basically the same thing, but without the lag after you resize.

Comment: @ahruss doesn't background size only apply to background images rather than HTML images?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is both dynamically resizing the image and changing its absolute position when the viewport is resized. There's a property below called "refreshOnResize".

https://static.squarespace.com/static/ta/50130f1ae4b006ef41174e6b/2013/scripts/fullscreen.js

```
YUI.add( 'squarespace-fullscreen', function( Y ) {

  Y.namespace( 'Squarespace' );

  var settings = {
    container: null,
    slides: '.slide',     /* string selector of slide elements */
    elements: {
      next: '.arrow-wrapper.right',
      previous: '.arrow-wrapper.left',
      controls: '#dotControls, #numberControls, #tinyThumbControls'
    },
    loop: false,
    detectColor: false,
    designOptions: {
      clickBehavior: true,
      // easing: Y.Easing.easeInOutExpo,
      speed: 1,
      autoHeight: false,
      preloadCount: 2,
      transition: 'fade',
      transitionOptions: { }
    },
    loaderOptions: { fill: true },
    refreshOnResize: true,
    refreshOnOrientationChange: true,
    afterInit: null,
    onSlideChange: null,
    afterSlideChange: null,
    touchHandler: {
      onSwipeDown: null,
      onSwipeUp: null
    },
    isTouchscreen: false,
    colorDetectCorners: ['topLeft', 'topRight', 'bottomLeft', 'bottomRight', 'suggestedbg']
  };

  Y.Squarespace.Fullscreen = function(userSettings) {

    settings = Y.merge(settings, userSettings);

    var galleries = [],
        galleryIndex = 0,
        $images;

    var autoPlay  = (Y.Squarespace.Template.getTweakValue('gallery-auto-play')+'' === "true"),
        playSpeed = parseFloat(Y.Squarespace.Template.getTweakValue('galleryPlaySpeed')),
        fitOrFill = Y.Squarespace.Template.getTweakValue('gallery-style');

    function init() {

      if (!Y.one(settings.slides)) {
        return false;
      }

      if (!settings.container) {
        throw 'container is required';
      }
      var galleryConfig = {
        container: null,
        slides: settings.slides,
        elements: {
          next: settings.elements.next,
          previous: settings.elements.previous,
          controls: settings.elements.controls
        },
        lazyLoad: true,
        loop: autoPlay,
        autoplay: autoPlay,
        autoplayOptions: {
          randomize: false,
          timeout: playSpeed * 1000,
          pauseOnMouseover: []
        },
        design: 'stacked',
        designOptions: settings.designOptions,
        keyboard: false,
        loaderOptions: settings.loaderOptions,
        refreshOnResize: settings.refreshOnResize,
        // deeplink urls for gallery collections only (indexes tricky)
        historyHash: Y.one('body').hasClass('collection-type-gallery')
      }; 

      if (settings.container._nodes) {
        settings.container.each(function(container) {
          $images = Y.all(settings.slides + ' img[data-src]');
        });

        for (var i=0; i<settings.container.size(); i++) {

          galleryConfig.container = settings.container.item(i);

          var gallery = new Y.Squarespace.Gallery2(galleryConfig);
          gallery.on('currentIndexChange', function(event) {
            Y.fire('fullscreen:on-slide-change', event);
          });

          gallery.after('currentIndexChange', function(event) {
            Y.fire('fullscreen:after-slide-change', event);
          });
          galleries.push(gallery);
        }
      } else {
        $images = settings.container.all('img[data-src]');

        galleryConfig.container = settings.container;
        var gallery = new Y.Squarespace.Gallery2(galleryConfig);

        gallery.on('currentIndexChange', function(event) {
          Y.fire('fullscreen:on-slide-change', event);
        });

        gallery.after('currentIndexChange', function(event) {
          Y.fire('fullscreen:after-slide-change', event);
        });
        galleries.push(gallery);
      }

      adjustColors(0);

      setupTweakListener();

      if (typeof settings.afterInit == 'function') {
        settings.afterInit();
      }
      Y.on('fullscreen:on-slide-change', function(e) { onSlideChange(e); });
      Y.on('fullscreen:after-slide-change', function(e) { afterSlideChange(e); });

    }
    init();

    this.getGallery = function(value) {
      return galleries[value];
    };

    this.getCurrentGallery = function() {
      return galleries[galleryIndex];
    };

    this.getGalleries = function() {
      return galleries;
    }

    this.refresh = function() {
      for (var i=0; i<galleries.length; i++) {
        galleries[i].refresh();
      }
    };

    this.getGalleryIndex = function(value) {
      return galleryIndex;
    };

    this.setGalleryIndex = function(value) {
      if (value < 0) {
        value = 0;
      }
      galleryIndex = value;
    };

    this.isLastEntry = function() {
      var currentGallery = galleries[galleryIndex];
      return (currentGallery.get('slides').size()-1 == currentGallery.get('currentIndex'));
    };

    this.isLastGallery = function() {
      return (galleryIndex == galleries.length-1);
    }

    this.destroy = function() {
      for (var i=0; i<galleries.length; i++) {
        galleries[i].destructor();
      }
    };

    this.adjustColors = function() {
      adjustColors(galleries[galleryIndex].get('currentIndex'));
    }

    function onSlideChange(event) {
      if (typeof settings.onSlideChange == 'function') {
        settings.onSlideChange(event);
      }
    }

    function afterSlideChange(event) {
      adjustColors(galleries[galleryIndex].get('currentIndex'));

      if (typeof settings.afterSlideChange == 'function') {
        settings.afterSlideChange(event);
      }

    }

    function getWindowWidth() {
      return Y.one('body').get('winWidth');
    }

    function adjustColors(slideIndex) {
      var slideImage = galleries[galleryIndex].getSlides().item(slideIndex).one('img'),
          bodyClasses = Y.one('#canvas').get('className'),
          currentColor;

      if (!slideImage) return;

      // Adjust foreground colors
      bodyClasses = bodyClasses.replace(/color-weight-[\w|\-]*\b/g, ''); // remove color weight classes
      Y.one('#canvas').set('className', bodyClasses);
      Y.Array.each(settings.colorDetectCorners, function(corner) {
        corner = corner.toLowerCase();
        var weight = slideImage.getAttribute('data-weight-'+corner);
        if (weight) {
          Y.one('#canvas').addClass('color-weight-'+corner+'-'+weight);
        }
      });

      // And background color
      if (Y.one('body.color-detect-gallery-background')) {
        var slide = galleries[galleryIndex].getSlides().item(slideIndex),
            color = slideImage.getAttribute('data-color-suggestedbg');
        if (color) {
          Y.one('body').setStyle('backgroundColor',color);
          if (Y.one('body').get('winWidth') < 640 && slide.one('.has-info')) {
            slide.one('.image-detail-wrapper').setStyle('backgroundColor', color);
          }
        }

        currentColor = color;
      } else {
        currentColor = Y.one('body.show-info .sqs-active-slide .imageWrapper.has-info, body.gallery-style-center') ? Y.one('body').getStyle('background-color') : slideImage.getAttribute('data-color-suggestedbg') || slideImage.getAttribute('data-color-topright');
      }

      if (currentColor) {
        var rgba = currentColor.match(new RegExp('rgba?\\((\\d+),\\s*(\\d+),\\s*(\\d+)'));
        if (rgba) {
          currentColor = rgb2hex(rgba[1],rgba[2],rgba[3]);
        }

        Y.one('#canvas').addClass('color-weight-' + getLightness(currentColor));
      }
    }

    function rgb2hex(r, g, b) {
      var parts = [r,g,b];

      for (var i = 0; i <= 2; ++i) {
        parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i], 10).toString(16);

        if (parts[i].length == 1)
          parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
      }

      return '#'+parts.join('');
    }

    function getLightness(hexcolor) {
      if (hexcolor && hexcolor.length > 0 && hexcolor.length <= 7) {
        hexcolor = hexcolor.replace('#', '');
        return ((parseInt(hexcolor, 16) > 0xffffff/2) ? 'light' : 'dark');
      } else {
        return '';
      }
    }

    function setupTweakListener() {

      var bRefresh = false;
      new TweakListener('gallery-transition', function(value) {
        bRefresh = true;
      });

      new TweakListener('gallery-index-style', function(value) {
        bRefresh = true;
      });

      new TweakListener('gallery-initial-view', function(value) {
        bRefresh = true;
      });

      new TweakListener('gallery-auto-play', function(value) {
        for (var i=0; i<galleries.length; i++) {
          galleries[i].set('autoplay', value);
        }
      });

      new TweakListener('galleryPlaySpeed', function(value) {
        for (var i=0; i<galleries.length; i++) {
          galleries[i].set('autoplayOptions.timeout', value*1000);
        }
      });

      new TweakListener('gallery-style', function(value) {
        $images.each(function(image) {
          refreshImageStyle(image, image.hasClass('cover') ? 'Fill' : value);
        });
      });

      /*
      new TweakListener('color-detect-for-fullscreen', function(value) {
        settings.detectColor = (value === "true");
        if (settings.detectColor) {
          adjustColors(galleries[galleryIndex].get('currentIndex'));
        } else {
          galleries[galleryIndex].getSlides().setStyle('backgroundColor', null);
        }
      }); */

      Y.Global.on('tweak:beforeopen', Y.bind(function(f){
        Y.later(500, this, function() {
          for (var i=0; i<galleries.length; i++) {
            galleries[i].refresh();
          }
        });
      }));

      Y.Global.on('tweak:close', Y.bind(function(f){
        if (bRefresh) {
          window.location.reload(true);
        }
      }));
    }

    function refreshImageStyle(image, fitOrFill) {
      if (image && image.loader) {
        if (fitOrFill == 'Center') {
          image.loader.setAttrs({fit: true});
        } else {
          image.loader.setAttrs({fill: true});
        }
      }
    }

  };

  var TweakListener = function(tweakName, callBack) {
    function init() {
      if (Y.Global) {
        Y.Global.on('tweak:change', Y.bind(function(f){
          if ((f.getName() == tweakName) && (typeof callBack === 'function')) {
            callBack(f.getValue());
          }
        }));
      }
    }
    init();
  };


}, '1.0', { requires: [ 'node' ] });
```